# How to return boolean with list.index?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to return a boolean with list.index() and if it possible.
I had tried:

```
def random():
    gobal cases_occupées
    cases_occupées=[]
    case = randint(0,99)
    if cases_occupées.index(case) == False:
        return case
    else
        random()
```

But with that code that return an exception ValueError if, so I tried to do something else:

```
def random():
global cases_occupées
case=randint(0,99)
while True:
    try:
        cases_occupées.index(case)
        break
    except ValueError:
        cases_occupées.append(case)
        return case
random()
```

But now I have an exception TypeError, I'm sure there is a way with "cases_occupées.index(case) == False" but I don'y find how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my bad english !

Comment: So you want to see if something's in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if an item is in a list like you're trying to do, use the `in` operator:

```
def random():
    global cases_occupées
    cases_occupées=[]
    if case not in cases_occupées:
        return case
    else:
        random()
```

`list.index` is used to find where an item is located inside a list, and as you've noticed, it throws an exception if the item isn't in the list.

From the Python documentation:

> The operators `in` and `not in` test for collection membership. `x in s` evaluates to true if `x` is a member of the collection `s`, and false otherwise. `x not in s` returns the negation of `x in s`.

Comment: Yeah it is that, thanks for your answer ! Now I will try to fix an other little problem ^^"